# active directory slow logins

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

I have a quick question about domain controller requirements. We have about 600 users in 1 large network and a few terminal servers. We have about 300 users logging into their machines around the same time and that takes a while for the login to start. We also see high load on the DCs during that hour time frame where there is an influx of simultaneous logins. The lsass.exe process is using most of the server memory and high CPU.

There are 2 domain controllers in the environment with 4 GB or ram each. What do you recommend to help with the login issue? I an thinking adding an additional 2-3 server 2003 DCs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at those two posts.

http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2007/08/20/troubleshooting-high-lsass-cpu-utilization-on-a-domain-controller-part-1-of-2.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2007/08/20/troubleshooting-high-lsass-cpu-utilization-on-a-domain-controller-part-2-of-2.aspx

And please give more details about your enviroment. Did you change anything before the problem arose?
What kind of terminalserver farm do you use?

Comment: I am new to the environment and from what I understand this issue always existed. There are 3 terminal servers( server 2003 enterprise) with about 200 users connecting at any given time.

Comment: Do you mean 200 users are connecting or are connected at a given time?
If you mean connected, how many users are actually logging in per minute?

Comment: i'm thinking 10 users per minute over an hour. the server is extremely slow which may lead me to believe the issue is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it could be AV related. Have you followed your AV vendor's guide for running it on a DC?

just for reference, I have a 40,000+ object AD and my DCs all have 4GB RAM and a single vCPU and they aren't even close to breaking a sweat.

Comment: How many DCs are you running? The environment has 2 DCs. Their is only high load when a bulk of the users are looking into the server.

Comment: 3 on our main site, which has well over 1000 users. We only have a single DC in our lab site, which regularly sees 15,000+ logins in a day.